# Using itemprop without itemtype

Tags: html, seo, microdata

If I understand it correctly, it is possible to use `itemprop` without `itemtype`. Is this true?

If so, what's the difference in terms of SEO? Is it better to use it with `itemtype`? I am guessing yes, obviously, but what if the Microdata is not equal to the site you have? For example, I have a dictionary and I could use book, but would this be a good thing to do? I don't know how Google will see this. It would be not fine to get a penalty because of bad use.

So: Do I have to use schema.org schemes?

Comment: What is your use case for using itemprop without itemscope?

Comment: Because I can't find a proper microformat... It's neither a book, nor a thing...

Comment: itemscope has nothing to do with the schema/microformat. It's boolean. Do you mean itemtype?

Comment: Yes, I meant itemtype indeed... Do I have to use that?

Comment: I changed the title/question accordingly (because you ask about `itemtype` instead of `itemscope`; for this, there’s the question: [Is 'itemprop' without parent 'itemscope' valid? Does it create an item?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21369695/1591669)).

Answer (score 1):

It's valid to use `itemprop` without `itemtype`, but any meaning of the `itemprop`s will be private. In order for that meaning to be shared with public microdata consumers, it will be necessary to associate it with an `itemtype` that is understood by that consumer.

Comment: So if I want to get a better SEO, I have to use itemtype? Alright then... But what if I use the wrong itemtype? Does this affect the SEO as well?

Comment: That kind of thing is hard to answer conclusively. It's in the interest of search engines to provide to their users, a list of the best matches for any given search query. (because the better the search results, the more they will be used, and the more money can thus be made from advertising) To that end, If they find it helpful to be tolerant of incorrect or missing itemtypes, no doubt they will implement that tolerance. Equally, if they get best results from being strict about particular itemtypes, then they will ignore incorrect ones.

Comment: I understand that, but is using a wrong itemtype equal to a SEO penalty?

Comment: @user2299147: Such SEO advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow (might be appropriate on [webmasters.se] instead). I think you should accept Alohci’s answer, as it answers your question as far as it can and should be answered here on SO.