# Is 'itemprop' without parent 'itemscope' valid? Does it create an item?

Tags: microdata

In the following example, Microdata’s `itemref` attribute is used to add the `email` property to the `Person` item (both from a fictive Microdata vocabulary).

```html
<body>

 <div itemscope itemtype="http://example.org/Person" itemref="orphan">
   <span itemprop="name">Alice</span>
 </div>

 <div id="orphan" itemprop="email">
   alice@example.com
 </div>

</body>
```

**Is this valid Microdata?**

If I understand the ["Associating names with items" algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#associating-names-with-items) correctly, the "`itemref`ed" properties are not *moved* but *copied*, which leaves this "orphan" `itemprop` without an item parent.

There are [three valid cases for `itemprop` values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#names%3a-the-itemprop-attribute). The following one seems to come closest:

> If the item is not a typed item: a string that contains no "." (U+002E) characters and no ":" (U+003A) characters.

(Which would mean that the orphaned property is not a "defined property name", i.e., it doesn’t belong to the fictive vocabulary anymore (only the "copied" property does).)

But: there is [no "item" involved, as there is no `itemscope`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#concept-item).

So you can’t specify `itemprop` without a parent `itemscope` at all? [Doesn‘t seem so](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#names%3a-the-itemprop-attribute):

> Every HTML element may have an `itemprop` attribute specified […]

What am I’m missing in the Microdata specification?

Does an `itemprop` without an `itemscope` parent create an *item*?

Comment: Interesting question. But I can't see why you think the itemref'd properties are copied, as opposed to just being included in a collection. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Alohci: I probably don’t use the correct terminology here (I’m not sure if I understand "being included in a collection"). What I mean: After the orphan property is added to the Person item (via `itemref`) this property is not "removed", i.e., it stays at its place and is (in addition to being used by Person) an orphan property (that could be `itemref`'d by other items in addition, of course).

Comment: Related [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22415921/1591669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec requirement is just that the itemprop is *used* in at least one item. There's no suggestion that I can see that being referenced by an itemref does not constitute a usage, nor that the itemprop is copied, and that it is the copy which is used not the original. So I think the spec requirements are fulfilled, and the microdata is valid.

Moreover, consider the intent of the spec. The underlying idea is that an itemprop that is not used by any item is pointless - a waste of typing - an therefore must be an authoring mistake. That is sufficient for mark-up to be considered invalid. Since that is not the case here, there is no justification for making such a construct invalid.

Comment: Right, thank you. I wonder why I didn’t notice this paragraph (end of [5.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#associating-names-with-items)) before: "A document must not contain any elements that have an `itemprop` attribute that would not be found to be a property of any of the items in that document were their properties all to be determined."

Answer (score 1):

1. **Is this valid Microdata?**

   - *Yes it is!*
2. **Does an itemprop without an itemscope parent create an item?**

   - *No it doesn't!*

---

An item is created by the itemscope attribute. With or with out properties, it is an item ones you declared it as an item. An itemprop declares the property of an item, it will never create it. It is still valid html to have the itemprop attribute declared on "orphans" sense there is no dependencies in html on attributes like does on elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#the-basic-syntax 9:th example describes the topic bit.

I work with these type of extractions a lot. The way I designed the software is to look for the root of every item, that's where the scope is declared. I then extend the scope if a reference is declared. I never look for properties outside the scope sense it's irrelevant.

Comment: Good example from the spec, thank you ([in the *Note*, it’s the 9th example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#the-basic-syntax)). -- So would you agree that the definition of [allowed `itemprop` values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute) is misleading as it says (emphasis mine) "**If the item** is not a typed item"? From this definition, it seems that using property names for orphan `itemprop` wouldn’t be allowed (as there is no item in the first place, whether typed or not typed).

Comment: And just to be sure: If my example wouldn’t contain any `itemref`, it would still be valid, right?

Comment: Yes, it would still be valid without itemref specified!

Comment: Considering your first question. I can't say that I feel this is misleading. A typed item is an item with a specified `itemtype` attribute, if I understood you correctly? But I must say that the explanation is horribly complexed described in this case.

Comment: The linked section defines 4 cases of valid `itemprop` values: 2 cases are about using absolute URLs (not the case in my example), the other two cases are using strings (my case). But both of those two cases start with "If the item is […]", so according to this definition, there can be no string value for `itemprop` unless there is an item.

Comment: Update: I think it would be invalid if this property is not used somewhere on the page, i.e., "without `itemref` specified". Ref. quote in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369695/is-itemprop-without-parent-itemscope-valid-does-it-create-an-item#comment33952982_21419698) to the Alohci’s answer.