# schema.org VideoObject → itemprop will not validate with W3C Validator

Tags: w3c-validation, microdata, schema.org

I am using the schema.org VideoObject for video on my webpages. However when I run the W3C Validator I get the following errors for each property:

> The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

This occurs for every item property show below:

```
<div class="video-wrapper-inner" itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Name of the Video" />
            <meta itemprop="description" content="Description of the Video. " />
            <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="../images/thumbnail.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="http://player.vimeo.com/external/123456.hd.mp4?s=ddddd44ssdd43d23rf" />
            <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M10S" />
            <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2013-12-26T08:00:00+08:00" />
            <meta itemprop="transcript" content="Transcript from the video here." />

            <video poster="../images/thumbnail.jpg" controls><source src="http://video file location" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /></video>

</div>
```

By the way my web page is set up as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

My question is, what is the correct markup to pass the W3C Validator.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C Markup Validator complains because you use the [`video` property](http://schema.org/video) on the `div` (*VideoObject*).

(See this question if this is an error at all: [Is 'itemprop' without parent 'itemscope' valid? Does it create an item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21369695/1591669))

Do you have a parent item that references this *VideoObject* via the `video` property? If so, add it to your page and validate again (the error should be gone). If you don’t have such a parent item, you could probably remove this property.