# How to to use multiple Vocabularies with HTML5 Microdata (different vocab than schema.org)

Tags: microdata, schema.org, vocabulary

Say I have this valid microdata enhanced HTML snippet:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation">
  <div itemprop="legalName">Example</div>
</div>
```

(I have tested this with google's Structured Data Testing Tool.)

And now I want to add a property which is not available in schema.org but in a different vocab (in this case the W3C registered Org Vocab [1]):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation">
  <div itemprop="legalName">Example</div>
  <div itemprop="http://www.w3.org/ns/regorg#registration">XXX</div>
</div>
```

At least google claims:

`Error: Page contains property "http://www.w3.org/ns/regorg#registration" which is not part of the schema.`

I could remove the `itemtype` but I don't want this as it is a loss of fidelity [2]
Is there no other way of doing this? With RDFa this would be no problem.

**EDIT**

I've found [3] which proposes to duplicate the content but that's obviously not a nice solution.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-regorg/#ref_rov_registration

[2] [Using itemprop without itemtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309207/using-itemprop-without-itemtype)

[3] http://www.w3.org/wiki/Mixing_HTML_Data_Formats#Mixing_Vocabularies_using_Repeated_Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microdata (W3C Note) defines [which values `itemprop` may have](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute).

Using an absolute URI as `itemprop` value is *always* allowed.

Unless a vocabulary (like schema.org) specifies the use of the `http://www.w3.org/ns/regorg#registration` value in this context ("[…] allowed in this situation by a vocabulary specification"), it would be

> […] a proprietary item property name (i.e. one used by the author for private purposes, not defined in a public specification)

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool is not a validator. Its primary concern is reporting warnings regarding Google’s private use of schema.org, that’s why you also might get warnings about missing "required" properties (but [schema.org doesn’t define any required properties](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58143/17633) at all).

FWIW, [Yandex’ Structured data validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml) doesn’t report a problem with using the absolute URI as value.

Comment: Well Google's "testing tool" does _not_ claim that a property is missing, it is complaining that the property is not unknown in schema[.org I guess]. Do you know how a vocabulary could disallow the use of an item property name? I'm not sure whether this is formal or in prose. Apart from that, I think you are right, concerning the spec, my second example should be valid.

Comment: @vanthome: Regarding the required properties: This was just an example to explain that Google’s testing tool reports many things which don’t necessarily have something to do with the *correct* use of schema.org. -- I don’t think there is a way for a vocabulary to *disallow* something like that (vocabularies can document that something wouldn’t make sense etc., but this would usually not be a normative requirement, instead something like an informative guide).